# How does runtime memory allocation for local variable's work in embedded systems?

Tags: c, embedded, rtos

We are using ccrx compiler,  embOS RTOS
There is a function in the code,

```
void fun( ) 
{
    if(condition) 
    { int a;}
    else if(condition1)
   {int b;}............ 
    else
   { int z;}
}
```

Whenever the function gets called, related thread stack overflows. If few of the int variable declarations are commented, the thread stack does not get overflowed.

How is the stack allocated? Doesn't the memory get allocated after a condition becomes successful?

Comment: I don't know much about the ccrx compiler, but surely you could look at a disassembly listing to see whether `a`, `b`, and `z` are conditionally allocated in the if branches or all allocated at the beginning of the function.

Comment: @David Grayson Thanks for the suggestion. I don't have any debugger for the system on which I am working.

Comment: Disassembling is different from debugging.  You need a disassembler or a debugger.  And many compilers can output assembly without needing a disassembler.

Comment: @David Grayson Okay. I will check

Comment: You can use online compiler to do so. [Here a little example](https://godbolt.org/g/T20pyT)

Comment: What is a "thread overflow"? Do you get seg fault? Stack overflow?

Comment: If you get a stack overflow just from allocating a few variables extra, then you are probably low on stack memory in general. In that case it is not related to this specific function, but to your overall program design.

Comment: @Lundin, but the memory for local variable in this case should get assigned only if the condition is true. That is not happening.

Comment: It depends on optimization settings of your compiler. As already suggested, you should check the assembler...

Comment: How memory is allocated when a function is called is very system-specific. It may be that the compiler allocates a stack frame no matter how the function is executed. Or it might as well not use the stack at all, but CPU registers. In order to know what happens in your case you have to read the disassembly and/or the compiler manual. It is probably not particularly interesting to know why the stack overflow is in this specific function though. You'll want to focus on why you are getting a stack overflow in the first place. The stack size needs to have much better margins.

Comment: How much stack, in words, did you allocate for this thread?  How many other functions before this one is called?  How many locals in them and what size are they?

Comment: 'I don't have any debugger for the system on which I am working' - that's a very bad plan/design.

Comment: those variable declarations are all inside a pair of opening/closing braces, so those braces are the limit of their scope, so they will not be visible in any of the rest of the code.  Given the posted code, only `sizeof(int)` bytes will be allocated on the stack.  That should not be a problem.  I.E. the posted code is not a problem.  Please post code that actually exhibits the problem of stack overflow AND post the microprocessor/microcontroller where this is to be run.  BTW: how many threads are being created?  Suggest posting the whole thread code and the code that creates the thread

Comment: @LPs I checked with lowest optimization setting. As per the observation it did not affect. But I need to dig a bit as many of other options have been set for the compiler. Yes, I will try with disassembler.

Comment: @Lundin As this function is newly added and is actually declaring local variable of large size(in actual code these are structures with sizes  100 to400 bytes). So the stack overflow is expected. As per my seniors, because of variable declaration inside if, this should not result in stack overflow, as only one of the condition will be true at the time of execution. That is why I need a proper explanation of why this is possible.

Comment: @user3629249 Can the choice of microcontroller affect this??

Comment: @ManaliBhadsalkar There's no way around checking the disassembly then. Make sure that optimizations are enabled. And indeed the choice of microcontroller is highly relevant, as that dictates how the whole ABI ends up. Simple microcontrollers will just push/pop individual data registers as they go, while more advanced ones will use stack frames. And stack frames might mean that memory has to be pre-allocated to cover all use-cases.

Comment: If there is no way around the stack allocation, a possible work-around could perhaps be to move the conditions outside the function. `if(condition1) func1(); else if(condition2) func2(); ...`

Comment: @Lundin thanks for the inputs.

Comment: @user3629249 microcontroller used is rx610 by Renesas.

Comment: It has 128k RAM... the program design would have to be completely haywire in order to run out of memory.

Comment: @Lundin :D There are 20 threads and few of the features added later were probably not planned,like the feature I am working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets take GCC for example

```
void fun( int condition, int condition1 )
{
    if(condition)
    { int a; a=5;}
    else if(condition1)
   {int b; b=7;}
    else
   { int z; z=9; }
}
```

and pick a target, not going to pay for or whatever to get ccrx...

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e52db004    push    {r11}       ; (str r11, [sp, #-4]!)
   4:   e28db000    add r11, sp, #0
   8:   e24dd01c    sub sp, sp, #28
   c:   e50b0018    str r0, [r11, #-24] ; 0xffffffe8
  10:   e50b101c    str r1, [r11, #-28] ; 0xffffffe4
  14:   e51b3018    ldr r3, [r11, #-24] ; 0xffffffe8
  18:   e3530000    cmp r3, #0
  1c:   0a000002    beq 2c <fun+0x2c>
  20:   e3a03005    mov r3, #5
  24:   e50b3008    str r3, [r11, #-8]
  28:   ea000007    b   4c <fun+0x4c>
  2c:   e51b301c    ldr r3, [r11, #-28] ; 0xffffffe4
  30:   e3530000    cmp r3, #0
  34:   0a000002    beq 44 <fun+0x44>
  38:   e3a03007    mov r3, #7
  3c:   e50b300c    str r3, [r11, #-12]
  40:   ea000001    b   4c <fun+0x4c>
  44:   e3a03009    mov r3, #9
  48:   e50b3010    str r3, [r11, #-16]
  4c:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
  50:   e28bd000    add sp, r11, #0
  54:   e49db004    pop {r11}       ; (ldr r11, [sp], #4)
  58:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

without the allocations

```
void fun( int condition, int condition1 )
{
    if(condition)
    { int a;/* a=5;*/}
    else if(condition1)
   {int b;/* b=7;*/}
    else
   { int z; /*z=9;*/ }
}
```

even with no optimization these variables are dead code and optimized out

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e52db004    push    {r11}       ; (str r11, [sp, #-4]!)
   4:   e28db000    add r11, sp, #0
   8:   e24dd00c    sub sp, sp, #12
   c:   e50b0008    str r0, [r11, #-8]
  10:   e50b100c    str r1, [r11, #-12]
  14:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
  18:   e28bd000    add sp, r11, #0
  1c:   e49db004    pop {r11}       ; (ldr r11, [sp], #4)
  20:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

There are some bytes on the stack for alignment, they could have shaved some off and stayed aligned but that is another topic.

The point here is that just because in the high level language your variables are only used in a portion of the function doesnt mean that the compiler has to do it that way, compilers certainly gcc, tend to do all of their stack allocation at the beginning of the function and cleanup at the end.  As was done here...

This is not unlike

```
int fun( void )
{
    static int x;
    x++;
    if(x>10) return(1);
    if(fun()) return(1);
    return(0);
}
```

which gives

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e59f2030    ldr r2, [pc, #48]   ; 38 <fun+0x38>
   4:   e5923000    ldr r3, [r2]
   8:   e2833001    add r3, r3, #1
   c:   e353000a    cmp r3, #10
  10:   e5823000    str r3, [r2]
  14:   da000001    ble 20 <fun+0x20>
  18:   e3a00001    mov r0, #1
  1c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  20:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
  24:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <fun>
  28:   e2900000    adds    r0, r0, #0
  2c:   13a00001    movne   r0, #1
  30:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
  34:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  38:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0

Disassembly of section .bss:

00000000 <x.4089>:
   0:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

it is a local variable but by being static goes into the global pool, not allocated on the stack like other local variables (or optimized into registers).

Although interesting that this was a case where it didnt allocate on the stack right away, although that is good in this case, dont want to burden the stack with recursion if you dont have to.  Nice optimization.

No reason to assume that the stack pointer will change multiple times throughout the function because of what you did in the high level language.  My guess is it makes developing the compiler easier to do it all in one shot up front even though that is wasteful on memory.  On the other hand as you go would cost more instructions (space and time).

Comment: I have a faint memory gcc added on some 4.x or 5.x version options to consider RAM-constraint targets. This depends all not just on those, but the whole code. A single added/removed variable can change everything. Of course this also depends on the platform architecture and the ABI (no. of registers, caller/callee saved registers, etc.).

Comment: The above was gcc 6.x and yes over time compilers will change gcc, 2.x, 3.x 4.x. 5.x. 6.x have all changed from prior versions for the same target (ARM in this case).  and certainly it only takes one variable or one line of code to push you over the edge to run out of registers and then need a stack frame or to make the stack requirements much worse.  If you call that function a lot then it then just multiplies your stack use.

Comment: people are taught to think of globals as bad, but in the case of a very memory contrained environment like an mcu, globals are allocated at compile time you know going in exactly what your consumption is.  local variables will vary with compiler and version, take a working, released firmware today, make one line modification tomorrow and total failure.  so you have to do your analysis of stack consumption for every released build.  not just looking at the C code but looking at the compiler output

Comment: Using globals (I prefer going with `static` locals iff I have to use static variables) might not really change the problem on certain architectures. temporary (anonymous) objects could still result in added stack usage. The only way to solve this is to profile stack usage, too, which is not a sinmple task on embedded systems.

Comment: Just checked: gcc provides a lot of options to check stack usage and layout. `-fstack-reuse` sounds interesting for this problem. Negative effect is: it complicated debugging, but that is normal when optimising code. That's why it is a good idea to use the largest device (RAM/Flash/clock) during debugging and not the cheaper, smaller device targeted.

Comment: good to know the tool helps.  eventually you have to figure out what device you are going to use and use it so have to figure out the ram usage, true might be easier starting larger getting a functional version of the code then start optimizing for resource usage...